# Como publicar posts em massa via banco de dados

Tags: mysql, wordpress

eu estou criando um site de animes.
Estou usando o theme BeTube da themeforest.
Queria postar vários animes de uma vez só via banco, pois postar um a um vai dar muito trabalho.
Atualmente quando posto ele fica como na imagem abaixo:
[image: Exemplo do vídeo]

E quando eu vou postar via banco ele aparesse no home, mas quando vou abrir ele não abre... fica carregando...

O vídeo é um player personalizado. O flowpayer que é integrado no post ao escrever um novo post...

Minha ideia é adicionar vários animes ao mesmo tempo via banco, e adicionar as categorias e o link do vídeo ao mesmo tempo...
Eu até procurei no banco mas nãosei onde fica....

meu script tá assim:

```
INSERT INTO `wp_posts` (`ID`, `post_author`, `post_date`, `post_date_gmt`, `post_content`, `post_title`, `post_excerpt`, `post_status`, `comment_status`, `ping_status`, `post_password`, `post_name`, `to_ping`, `pinged`, `post_modified`, `post_modified_gmt`, `post_content_filtered`, `post_parent`, `guid`, `menu_order`, `post_type`, `post_mime_type`, `comment_count`) VALUES (NULL, '1', '2019-05-04 15:31:27', '2019-05-04 18:31:27', '\r\n 
Após uma cidade ser aniquilada, uma jovem chamada Yuki diz ser a única sobrevivente. Takuya, um contrabandista solitário, seguem junto com Yuki em uma jornada em direção à cidade, agora conhecida como Lost, entretanto diversos obstáculos inesperados aparecem no caminho deles. Organizações secretas e conspirações escondidas aguardam Yuki e Takuya enquanto se aproximam do mistério por trás de Lost. \r\n', 'Shoumetsu Toshi 03', '', 'publish', 'open', 'open', '', 'shoumetsu-toshi-03', '', '', '2019-05-04 15:31:45', '2019-05-04 18:31:45', '', '289', '', '0', 'post', '', '0');

INSERT INTO `wp_posts` (`ID`, `post_author`, `post_date`, `post_date_gmt`, `post_content`, `post_title`, `post_excerpt`, `post_status`, `comment_status`, `ping_status`, `post_password`, `post_name`, `to_ping`, `pinged`, `post_modified`, `post_modified_gmt`, `post_content_filtered`, `post_parent`, `guid`, `menu_order`, `post_type`, `post_mime_type`, `comment_count`) VALUES (NULL, '1', '2019-05-04 15:28:30', '2019-05-04 18:28:30', '', 'Shoumetsu-Toshi', '', 'inherit', 'open', 'closed', '', 'shoumetsu-toshi', '', '', '2019-05-04 15:28:30', '2019-05-04 18:28:30', '', NULL, 'http://localhost/anime/wp-content/uploads/2019/05/Shoumetsu-Toshi.jpg', '0', 'attachment', 'image/jpeg', '0');

INSERT INTO `wp_posts` (`ID`, `post_author`, `post_date`, `post_date_gmt`, `post_content`, `post_title`, `post_excerpt`, `post_status`, `comment_status`, `ping_status`, `post_password`, `post_name`, `to_ping`, `pinged`, `post_modified`, `post_modified_gmt`, `post_content_filtered`, `post_parent`, `guid`, `menu_order`, `post_type`, `post_mime_type`, `comment_count`) VALUES (NULL, '1', '2019-05-04 15:31:27', '2019-05-04 18:31:27', '\r\n 
Após uma cidade ser aniquilada, uma jovem chamada Yuki diz ser a única sobrevivente. Takuya, um contrabandista solitário, seguem junto com Yuki em uma jornada em direção à cidade, agora conhecida como Lost, entretanto diversos obstáculos inesperados aparecem no caminho deles. Organizações secretas e conspirações escondidas aguardam Yuki e Takuya enquanto se aproximam do mistério por trás de Lost. \r\n', 'Shoumetsu Toshi 03', '', 'inherit', 'closed', 'closed', '', NULL, '', '', '2019-05-04 15:31:27', '2019-05-04 18:31:27', '', '289', '', '0', 'revision', '', '0')
```

Answer (score 1):

Consegui resolver...

Na tabela **wp-post** ficam armazenados os posts.

Na tabela **wp-terms** ficam armazenados as categorias, mas na tabela wp-posts não há referencia entre o id da categoria da tabela **wp-terms**.

Na tabela **wp_term_relationships** o **object_id** é o **id do post**, a ele temos o **term_taxonomy_id** que é outro valor numérico.
Na **tabela wp_term_taxonomy** temos o **term_taxonomy_id** da tabela **wp_term_relationships** e ao lado temos o **term_id** que é o valor correspondente a categoria na tabela **wp-terms**

Então basicamente vc precisa fazer 3 inserts.

wp_posts

wp_postmeta

wp_term_relationships

Answer (score 1):

Parece que você já resolveu com SQL, tudo certo, mas fica o registro: você pode usar o [WP-CLI](https://wp-cli.org/) para resolver isso via linha de comando, ou escrevendo um script em php, ao invés de fazer toda essa manobra:

[wp post create](https://developer.wordpress.org/cli/commands/post/create/)

```
wp post create --post_title="Titulo do Post" --post_content="Conteudo" --post_category="categoria1,categoria2,categoria3"
```